# Sencha Touch 2.0 and MessageBox : listeners

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

i have a little sencha touch 2.0 MVC application. packaged via PhoneGap.

I want a little message box which if touched/clicked will let the do something, lets say a couple of simple alert.

To obtain this i have writed this view :

```
Ext.define('mytest.view.Windowmsg', {
    extend: 'Ext.MessageBox',
    alias: 'widget.windowmsg',
    title: 'Clickable Message',
    config: {
        top:20,
        html : 'Click Me!',
        style:"  text-align:center;background-color:#822222;color:yellow;position:absolute;bottom:20;left:0;right:0;width:80%;margin-left:10%;text-align:center;",


        listeners: {
            tap:function(){
                alert ('Hello World!');
                alert ('Hello Earth!');
            }
        },
        modal:false,
        hidden:false 
    }
});
```

And in the controller i use this lines of code to add the message box to my panel :

```
....
var mylittlewindow = Ext.widget('windowmsg');
Ext.Viewport.add(mylittlewindow);
....
```

The message box is correctly visualized but i am not able to control the tap event related to it, like i thought i was doing with the 'listeners' configuration in the Ext.MessageBox.

My question is : Please, what's the right way to control the tap event on that MessageBox ?

Answer (score 0):

From Sencha Touch API

```
// Basic alert:
Ext.Msg.alert('Title', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', Ext.emptyFn);

// Prompt for user data and process the result using a callback:
Ext.Msg.prompt('Name', 'Please enter your name:', function(text) {
    // process text value and close...
});

// Confirmation alert
Ext.Msg.confirm("Confirmation", "Are you sure you want to do that?", Ext.emptyFn);
```

You need to configure the callback function of the alert if you want to execute some code when you tap on the OK button of the alert